# Cannot connect to a wireless network on MSI U135DX

Tags: wireless

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my MSI U135DX alongside with Windows 7. The problem is that it can detect wireless networks but can't connect to it. But when I'm on Windows 7 it works just fine. How can I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you don't give enough informations. 
It can be related to a driver problem (got the same problem once with the open source driver of a broadcom). 
Maybe just look first in "additionnal drivers" section to see if you have an other choice regarding wireless card driver. 
If it doesn't help. You should provide at least the results of commands lspci, ifconfig and lsmod to see which driver is loaded.